# C# compare time and date in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hy am trying to compare current date and trying to perform action when specific date comes. but it doesn't work in c# unity. 
here is code:

```
string over = "2017/06/28 22:38:30";
string dateAndTimeVar = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

if (dateAndTimeVar == over)
{
    print(dateAndTimeVar);
}
```

Comment: Well they'd have to match based on the second. Why are you converting them to strings instead of just letting the DateTime objects handle the comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the main problem you are having is using the "==" operator.

Since you are wanting it to be equal down to the second, you are relying on Unity to run your piece of code every second. If this is not the case, then your code may be missed when the time comes.

Since you are using strings you are stuck with this option. You could instead use DateTime objects to perform the comparison.

```
var over = DateTime.Parse("2019/04/01 17:09:10");
var dateAndTimeVar = System.DateTime.Now;

if (dateAndTimeVar >= over)
{
    print(dateAndTimeVar);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When I had common problem, I used `DateTime.Now` to get current time.
For comparring DateTime objects, it's easy to use [DateTime.Ticks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

As I understood from your code, you want to execute  `print(dateAndTimeVar);`, when comes the time.
It's better to compare, like:

```
if(DateTime.Now.Ticks >= dateTimeOver)
{
    print(dateAndTimeVar);
}
```

Comment: Why exactly is it better to compare the Ticks rather than the DateTime objects?

Answer (score 1):

```
string dateInput = "2017/06/28 22:38:30";
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInput);

if (DateTime.Now > parsedDate)
{
    print("It is Over");
}
```

You Can Parser to a DateTime, And Compare that.

Answer (score 0):

System.DateTime.Now, in its most basic form, uses the clock of the computer running the program. Since you're including seconds in your datetimes, for the conditional to evaluate to true you would have to evaluate it at the exact second specified in the string 'over'. Going from only the posted code it would be highly unlikely that you'd be able to run the program and evaluate the conditional at the exact second specified without something else to control the environment. A simple way to debug this would be to print out the variables or use a debugger to actually see what the computer is seeing at the time of execution.